# how to print id dynamily in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

say i have a function like below

```
<code>
<pre>
function messageHandler(user_id,add_remove_id)
 {
    var type=3;
    var data = 'user_id=' + user_id+'&add_remove_id='+add_remove_id+'&type='+type;
    alert(data);
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"add_rem_friend.php", 
        data:data,             
        success:function(html) {
  //**********************************************   
  // i want to put the value of add_remove_id, which i taking as argument/parameter      
          //   $('#add_remove_id').html(html); will not work
           // is there any way? 
 //************************************************* 
        }
        });     
        return false;
 }
</pre>
</code>
```

i want to put the value of add_remove_id, which i taking as argument/parameter

```
<pre>
 $('#add_remove_id').html(html); will not work
</pre>
```

is there any way?

Comment: $('#'+add_remove_id).html(html);

solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that: add_remove_id is a variable a string and you have to concatenate this string to the jquery selector.
Try this:

```
$('#'+add_remove_id).html(html);
```

If you use:

```
$('#add_remove_id').html(html);
```

jQuery search an element where the id = add_remove_id

Comment: Accept the answer to help other person with your same problem, this is how stacvkoverflow works. You are welcome! @MDTAHMIDHOSSAIN

Comment: have to wait more 6 mins . i will do it after 6 mins

Answer (score 1):

Just concat the strings properly

`$('#'+add_remove_id).html(html);`

And then this will definitely work